# Problems calling a javascript function with the output of a function

Tags: javascript, function, return-value

The problem in the code below is calling one function from another - the function domenu calls doarticle with the relevant page number OK but the doarticle function does not format with CSS at all. if I call the functions independently than everything works fine, it's only when I call one from the other that the problem appears.

MONITORING CSS WITH FIREBUG: All CSS data vanishes from the DOM when the doarticle function is called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=9" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=768" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/guide_icon.png"/>
<title>The Guide</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
    width:768px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
    }
    div, span
    {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:140%;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align:justify;
    color:#000000;
    }
    img.imgpadded
    {
    padding: 12px 7px 7px 7px ;
    }
    img.imgborder
    {
    width:764px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    span.footnum
    {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:110%;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#FF3300;
    }
    span.foottext
    {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:110%;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
    }
    div.topic
    {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#6D8BE6;
    }
    div.title
    {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:250%;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000000;
    }
    div.summary
    {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:115%;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
    }
    span.menutitle
    {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#6D8BE6;
    }
    span.menusummary
    {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:80%;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
    }
    div.bigquote
    {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:210%;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000033;
    }
    img.banner
    {
    width: 768px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    sup
    {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:50%;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FF3300;
    }
    blockquote
    {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
    margin:20px 0 20px 20px;
    padding:10px 10px 10px;
    background-color:#eee;
    border-left:4px solid #6D8BE6;
    }
    ul
    {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0px;
    }
    li
    {
    background-image:url(images/blue_square.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0px 5px; 
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:50px;
    }
</style>
```

Metas and CSS above

The article HTML rendering engine below...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doarticle (counter)
{
// document.body.innerHTML = "";
hhgaudio = 0;
strpos = 0;
hhgstring = "";

    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+7)) === "<HHGML>")
    {
        strpos = 7;
        if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+8)) == "<BANNER>") // large banner at the top of the article
        {
            strpos = strpos +8;

            while (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+9)) != "</BANNER>")
            {
                hhgstring = hhgstring + hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+1));
                strpos++;
            }
            strpos = strpos + 9;
            hhgstring = "<img id=\"banner\" src=\"" + imgpath + hhgstring + "\" style=\"vertical-align: top\"/>";
        }   
        hhgstring = "<img class=\"banner\" src=\"" + imgpath + "hhg_entry.jpg\" style=\"vertical-align: bottom\"/><br/>" + hhgstring;
        document.write(hhgstring);
        hhgstring = "<table frame=\"void\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\"><tr><td>";        
        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<div class=\"topic\">"+ (hhgdata[counter][0].toUpperCase()) + "<br/></div>"; // main article topic
        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<div class=\"title\">" + hhgdata[counter][1] + "</div>"; // main article title
        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<div class=\"summary\">" + (hhgdata[counter][3].toUpperCase()) + "</div>"; // article sub heading
        hhgstring = hhgstring + "</td></tr></table>"
        // if (hhgaudio == 0)
        // {
        //  hhgstring = hhgstring + "<audio autoplay=\"autoplay\"><source src=\"http://www.hyperspaces.co.uk/HHG/audio/HHG_noise.mp3\"></audio>"
        //  hhgaudio = 1;
        // }
        document.write(hhgstring);
        hhgstring = "";
        footernum = 0;

        while (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+8)) != "</HHGML>")
        {

            if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+8)) == "<BANNER>") // large banner image at full page width
            {
                strpos = strpos +8;

                while (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+9)) != "</BANNER>")
                {
                    hhgstring = hhgstring + hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+1));
                    strpos++;
                }
                strpos = strpos + 9;
                hhgstring = "<img class=\"imgborder\" src=\"" + imgpath + hhgstring +"\">";
                document.write(hhgstring);
                hhgstring = "";
            }

            if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+3)) == "<P>")
            {
                strpos = strpos + 3;
                hhgstring = hhgstring + "<div><table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"10\"><tr><td>";

                while (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+4)) != "</P>")
                {

                    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+4)) == "<IL>")
                    {
                        strpos = strpos +4;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<img class=\"imgpadded\" src=\"" + imgpath;

                        while (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+5)) != "</IL>")
                        {
                            hhgstring = hhgstring + hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+1));
                            strpos ++;
                        }
                        strpos = strpos + 5;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring  +"\" align=\"left\">";
                    }

                    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+4)) == "<IR>")
                    {
                        strpos = strpos +4;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<img class=\"imgpadded\" src=\"" + imgpath;

                        while (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+5)) != "</IR>")
                        {
                            hhgstring = hhgstring + hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+1));
                            strpos ++;
                        }
                        strpos = strpos + 5;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring  +"\" align=\"right\">";
                    }

                    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+3)) == "<B>") // bold function
                    {
                        strpos = strpos +3;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<b>";
                    }

                    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+4)) == "</B>") // stop bold function
                    {
                        strpos = strpos +4;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring + "</b>";
                    }

                    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+3)) == "<I>") // italic function
                    {
                        strpos = strpos +3;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<i>";
                    }

                    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+4)) == "</I>") // stop italic function
                    {
                        strpos = strpos +4;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring + "</i>";
                    }   

                    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+12)) == "<BLOCKQUOTE>") // blockquote function
                    {
                        strpos = strpos +12;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<blockquote>";

                        while (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+13)) != "</BLOCKQUOTE>")
                        {
                            hhgstring = hhgstring + hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+1));
                            strpos ++;
                        }
                        strpos = strpos + 13;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring  +"</blockquote>";
                    }

                    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+6)) == "<QBIG>") // large quote - big font
                    {
                        strpos = strpos +6;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<br/><br/><div class=\"bigquote\">";

                        while (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+7)) != "</QBIG>")
                        {
                            hhgstring = hhgstring + hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+1));
                            strpos ++;
                        }
                        strpos = strpos + 7;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring  +"</div>";

                        if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+4)) != "</P>") // add padding if mid-paragraph
                        {
                            hhgstring = "<br/>" + hhgstring;
                        }
                    }

                    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+6)) == "<LIST>") // item list function
                    {
                        strpos = strpos +6;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<ul>";

                        while (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+7)) != "</LIST>")
                        {
                            if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+6)) == "<ITEM>")
                            {
                                strpos = strpos +6;
                                hhgstring = hhgstring + "<li>";

                                while (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+7)) != "</ITEM>")
                                {
                                    hhgstring = hhgstring + hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+1));
                                    strpos ++;
                                }
                                strpos = strpos + 7;
                                hhgstring = hhgstring  +"</li>";    
                            }                           
                        }
                        strpos = strpos + 7;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring  +"</ul>";
                    }

                    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+5)) == "<BR/>") // single line break function
                    {
                        strpos = strpos +5;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<br/>";
                    }

                    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+5)) == "<TAB>") // single line break function
                    {
                        strpos = strpos +5;
                        hhgstring = hhgstring + tab;
                    }

                    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+10)) == "<FOOTNOTE>")
                    {
                        strpos = strpos +10;
                        ftext = footernum + 1;
                        fstring = "";
                        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<sup>" + ftext + "</sup>";

                        while (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+11)) != "</FOOTNOTE>")
                        {
                            fstring = fstring + hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+1));
                            strpos ++;
                        }
                        strpos = strpos + 11;
                        hhgfooter[footernum] = fstring;
                        footernum ++;
                    }

                    if (hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+1)) != "<") // add any normal text
                    {
                        hhgstring = hhgstring + hhgdata[counter][2].substring(strpos,(strpos+1));
                        strpos ++;
                    }
                }
            } // end of pagagraph

            hhgstring = hhgstring +"</td></tr></table></div>";
            strpos = strpos + 4;
            document.write(hhgstring);
            hhgstring = "";

        } // end of article
        // document.body.innerHTML = hhgstring;
        if (footernum != 0)
        {
            document.write("<br/>");
            for (f=0; f<footernum; f++)
            {
                ftext = f+1;
                hhgstring = tab + tab + "<span class=\"footnum\">" + ftext + ":  ";
                hhgstring = hhgstring + "<span class=\"foottext\">" + hhgfooter[f] + "</span></span><br/>";
                document.write(hhgstring);
            }
        }   
        document.write("<br/><table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"10\"><tr><td><span>Entry Ends.</span></tr></table><br/>");
    } // end of <HHGML>

} // end of records 

</script>
```

The menu listing function...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function domenu (lastrecord)
{
    hhgstring = "<br/><br/><table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">";
    for (counter=1; counter<lastrecord; counter++)
    {
        recnum = lastrecord - counter;
        // hhgstring = hhgstring + "<tr><td><img id=\"imgpadded\" src=\"" + imgpath + hhgdata[recnum][4] + "\" align=\"left\"></td>";
        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<tr><td>" + hhgdata[recnum][4] + "</td>";
        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<td><span class=\"menutitle\" onclick=\"doarticle('" +recnum+ "');\">" + tab + hhgdata[recnum][1] + "<br/></span>";
        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<span class=\"menusummary\">" + tab + hhgdata[recnum][3] + "</span></td></tr>";
    }
    hhgstring = hhgstring + "</table>";
    document.write(hhgstring);
    return(hhgselect);
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
```

The database bit...

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("XXXX","XXXX","XXXX");
    mysql_select_db("HHG", $con);
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else 
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles", $con);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    }
?> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    numrows = <?php echo $numrows; ?>;
    hhgdata = new Array(numrows);
    hhgfooter = new Array(10);
</script>

<?php
    $counter = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $hhgtitle = $row["hhgtitle"];
        $hhgtopic = $row["hhgtopic"];
        $hhgarticle = mysql_real_escape_string($row["hhgarticle"]);
        $hhgsummary = mysql_real_escape_string($row["hhgsummary"]);
        $hhgidimg = $row["hhgidimg"];
    ?>
```

Convert the PHP to Javascript vars...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        counter = <?php echo $counter; ?>; 
        hhgtitle = <?php echo '"'.$hhgtitle.'"'; ?>;
        hhgtopic = <?php echo '"'.$hhgtopic.'"'; ?>;
        hhgarticle = <?php echo '"'.$hhgarticle.'"'; ?>;
        hhgsummary = <?php echo '"'.$hhgsummary.'"'; ?>;
        hhgidimg = <?php echo '"'.$hhgidimg.'"'; ?>; 
        hhgdata[counter] = new Array(5);
        hhgdata[counter][0]= hhgtopic;
        hhgdata[counter][1]= hhgtitle;
        hhgdata[counter][2]= hhgarticle
        hhgdata[counter][3]= hhgsummary;
        hhgdata[counter][4]= hhgidimg;
    </script>

    <?php
    $counter++;
    }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

call the menu script ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
imgpath = "images/";
tab = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
hhgselect = domenu (numrows);
doarticle (hhgselect);
// document.body.innerHTML = ""; // clears the screen


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write:

```
hhgselect = dmenu(numrows);
```

and then

```
doarticle(hhgselect);
```

EDIT: or if you want to select at onclick why don't you just call doarticle inside the onclick event?

EDIT 2:

try:

```
 ... hhgstring + "<td><span id=\"menutitle\" onclick=\"doarticle('" +recnum+ "');\">"...
```

EDIT 3:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function domenu (lastrecord)
{
    hhgstring = "<br/><br/><table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">";
    for (counter=1; counter<lastrecord; counter++)
    {
        recnum = lastrecord - counter;
        // hhgstring = hhgstring + "<tr><td><img class=\"imgpadded\" src=\"" +     imgpath + hhgdata[recnum][4] + "\" align=\"left\"></td>";
        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<tr><td>" + hhgdata[recnum][4] + "</td>";
        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<td><span class=\"menutitle\" onclick=\"doarticle('" +recnum+ "');\">" + tab + hhgdata[recnum][1] + "<br/></span>";
        hhgstring = hhgstring + "<span class=\"menusummary\">" + tab + hhgdata[recnum][3] + "</span></td></tr>";
    }
hhgstring = hhgstring + "</table>";
document.write(hhgstring);
return(hhgselect);
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    imgpath = "images/"+imgmod+"/";
    tab = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    hhgselect = 0;
    domenu (numrows);
</script>
```

Comment: when I call do article in the on click event it loses all access to the CSS on the page - I have no idea why....

Comment: first try to use DOM createElement and appendChild it is more useful, second please verify if you use the correct calling in an inline call inside a string with parameter ( hint you should use a lot of escaped characters )

Comment: tried the hhgselect = domenu(numerous); method. Nothing happens. Are the onclicks ok or is there a better way to change a variable?

Comment: "<span id=\"menutitle\" onclick=\"hhgselect = " + recnum + "\";>" is escaped properly. I just triple checked. THanks.

Comment: OK Khael - tried the new onclick. the event fires but the new function cannot see any CSS ids or body formatting (maybe because it was fired within a table?).

Comment: @user1150866 what does doarticle actually does? it should see everything if it is global.

Comment: @user1150866 try making the document.write inside the body not the head as you are editing a table not a meta or a script tag.

Comment: I wonder if the id=\"menutitle\" in the SPAN affects everything linked from it. maybe <span onclick=...><span id=\"menutitle\"...></span></span> will do it...

Comment: @user1150866 you have more than 1 unique ID this is your problem i think.

Comment: tried running in head and body. no difference. What do you mean by more than one unique ID. I am learning so small words please. Cheers for the help.

Comment: well in CSS an ID should be unique on the page. You are generating more than one element with the ID=menutitle try changing to class="menutitle" and the css accordingly.

Comment: do article runs fine if called from body - all formatting colours etc OK. function is in HEAD.

Comment: #menutitle
  {
  font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size:100%;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#6D8BE6;
  }
HOw do I change this to a class?

Comment: `.menutitle` and you should use the EDIT 3 cause you have another 2 issues with other id's.

Comment: i have change the #menutitle to span.menutitle and replace all the ID's with CLASS. Still the same problem. SOrry.

Comment: try posting all the code. css html js and i would be glad to help.

Comment: span.menutitle
  {
  font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size:100%;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#6D8BE6;
  }
For example.

Comment: reedit your post for everyone to see with full ( ok not full but the most relevant code ) like even the doarticle function and you try to do. we are already asked not to extend the comments after comment situation we are in.

Comment: I have to sleep. I'll see what you make of it all tomorrow... A big thanks. T.

Answer (score 1):

hhgselect doesn't appear to be getting any new value anywhere, so, it makes sense that it will remain 0 and you'll always see the same result.

Where do you *think you're altering its value? It's a global variable and you're returning it from domenu(), although it's not being collected by anything, as we're already said. However, whether it's collected or not, since you're not actually modifying its value, it has no reason to be of use.

Comment: Done that (see Khael's answer above). No joy.